# C program debug window console won't stay

Tags: c

I have visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop installed and wrote first hello world world program.
When I compile it it shows no errors.
When I hit local windows debugger button the console window flashes with a result for 1/4 second and goes away.
What should I do to keep it there so that when I program longer codes I won't have any difficulty.

Thanks.

Comment: Goto Debug Menu->Press StartWithoutDebugging - Done...

Answer (score 0):

Adding `system("pause");` or `int x; scanf("%d", &x);` at the end of your `main()` function are popular options.

Comment: I think there's no `cin` in C.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following template on your programmes, whenever you compile a C programme using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013:

```
//#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
// un-comment the line above, if you want to
// be able to use functions like scanf instead
// of their more secure versions like scanf_s
#include <stdio.h>


int main( /* int argc, char ** argv */ ) {


    fflush( stdin );
    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

This is the most simple template you could use for MSVC 2013. Do not use `fflush( stdin );` in anywhere else, it has no defined behaviour elsewhere, it is microsoft-specific.